# .Net DirectorySearcher not retrieving all values in user object

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, directorysearcher

As part of the program I'm writing, I have to retrieve all user data from the current user's AD object.

Here is the code I'm using...

```
Try
    Dim RootEntry As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://**USER OU**")
    RootEntry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure

    Dim ds As New DirectorySearcher(RootEntry)

    ds.SizeLimit = System.Int32.MaxValue
    ds.PageSize = System.Int32.MaxValue

    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn") ' Common Name

    ' Personal
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName") ' Given Name
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn") ' Surname
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("fullname") ' Full Name (GN + SN)

    ' Comms
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("telephoneNumber") ' Tel # (from general)
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail") ' Email (from general)
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mobile") ' Mobile Phone (from Telephone)

    ' Job Role
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("title") ' Job Title (Organisation)
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("company") ' Company (Organisation)
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("department") ' Department (Organisation)

    ' Address
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("streetAddress")
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("l") ' City
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("st") ' State
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("postalCode") ' Post Code
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("co") ' Country

    ds.ServerTimeLimit = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 60)
    ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree

    ds.Filter = "(&(anr=" & username(1) & ")(objectCategory=person))"

    Dim searchresults As SearchResultCollection
    searchresults = ds.FindAll()

    Debug.Print("Search Results - " & searchresults.Count())

    For Each result In searchresults
        If Not result.Properties("givenName")(0) Is Nothing Then
            strForename = result.Properties("givenName")(0)
                Label1.Text = "Hello " & strForename & "!"
        End If
        If Not result.Properties("sn")(0) Is Nothing Then
                strSurname = result.Properties("sn")(0)
        End If
        If Not strSurname Is Nothing And Not strForename Is Nothing Then
                strName = result.Properties("givenName")(0) & " " & result.Properties("sn")(0)
        End If
        If Not result.Properties("title")(0) Is Nothing Then
                strTitle = result.Properties("title")(0)
        End If
        If Not result.Properties("company")(0) Is Nothing Then
                strCompany = result.Properties("company")(0)
        End If
        If Not result.Properties("department")(0) Is Nothing Then
                strDepartment = result.Properties("department")(0)
        End If

        If Not result.Properties("telephoneNumber")(0) Is Nothing Then
                strPhone = result.Properties("telephoneNumber")(0)
        End If
        If Not result.Properties("mobile")(0) Is Nothing Then
                strMobile = result.Properties("mobile")(0)
        End If
        If Not result.Properties("mail")(0) Is Nothing Then
                strEmail = result.Properties("mail")(0)
        End If

        If Not result.Properties("streetAddress")(0) Is Nothing Then
                strStreet = result.Properties("streetAddress")(0)
        End If
        If Not result.Properties("l")(0) Is Nothing Then
                strLocation = result.Properties("l")(0)
        End If
        If Not result.Properties("st")(0) Is Nothing Then
                strCounty = result.Properties("st")(0)
        End If
        If Not result.Properties("postalCode")(0) Is Nothing Then
                strPostCode = result.Properties("postalCode")(0)
        End If
        If Not result.Properties("co")(0) Is Nothing Then
                strCountry = result.Properties("co")(0)
        End If
        strAddress = strStreet
    Next

Catch ex As System.Exception
    Debug.Print(ex.Message)
End Try
```

If I run the program, the system returns all my AD settings, populating each in the box.

[image: Program imports my AD details][image: ADUC Address entry.]

If another user runs the program, the system returns only a partial result set, despite the items being completed on his ADUC properties dialog.

[image: Other User AD details missing][image: Other user ADUC, showing Address]

The Searcher is only returning 1 entry per user (given it sends the SAMAccountName) but I have set the `PageSize` and `SizeLimit` values to avoid the 1000 item issue.

I have also tried a simpler filter of `samaccountname= & username(1)`, but to no avail.

Am I running into some undocumented/unreported AD security issue? My account used to be a Domain Admin, but isn't anymore following a security review.

The problem isn't related to computers, because if I run the program via impersonation on his computer, my details are returned in full and vice-versa (his aren't).

Comment: Can you check if the other user is not delegated the rights to read those attributes - street, mobile, email, etc.? Also from what I can see, you're using a for-each loop which will bring only one user-record at a time as per your code. Please let me know is there something which I didn't understand in your question.

Comment: It retrieves one record by design. Please explain the delegation aspect further. How can I check? Why would a user be delegated access to their own user object?

Comment: Please go to that user's properties in ADUC(dsa.msc) -> Security Tab -> Authenticated Users -> Check these permission settings from the list: Read General Information, Read Personal Information, etc. Also, can you check and confirm this behaviour for any third/other user?

Comment: 'Read' is ticked for Read Exchange Information, Exchange Personal Information, General Information, Group Membership, Logon Information, Personal Information, Phone & Mail Options, Private Information & Public Information. I will attempt to test with another user shortly.

Comment: I've just tested with a dummy account and the same result happens.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I traced the problem to the following...

```
If Not result.Properties("mobile")(0) Is Nothing Then
    strMobile = result.Properties("mobile")(0)
    Inc_Mob.Checked = True
    Mob_TB.Text = strMobile
End If
```

Many users do not have mobile phone numbers and the DirectorySearcher will not create a null value if it tries to retrieve a value that is blank, it just fails to create it.

I wasn't handling it properly in the code and the Try loop wasn't explicitly stating what the problem was in the error message, instead just returning an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` error.